# How do I revert the space deletion behavior in IntelliJ IDEA 14?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I've just updated to IntelliJ IDEA 14 from version 13.  One difference I've found is that when I hit the backspace key it deletes a full tab stop worth of space characters, rather than deleting a single space at a time.  How do I revert the behavior to deleting a single space at a time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Settings/Editor/General/Smart Keys and uncheck *Backspace Smart Indent*.

Comment: Thanks. I was searching for "delete" and not "backspace", so I wasn't finding it in the settings.

Comment: In newer versions of IntelliJ (i'm on 2016.3) on the same preferences page there is an _Unindent_ dropdown you set to `Disabled`

Answer (score 0):

just press the insert key, you can toggle between these two types of cursor

Comment: I don't know whether this works on other operating systems, but the Macintosh keyboard doesn't have an insert key, so it definitely doesn't work on IntelliJ running on a Macintosh.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, please provide more details such as OS as they matter greatly in these issues.

Answer (score 0):

On IDEA 2023 it's
Settings > Editor > General > Smart Keys >
Unindent on Backspace - change to disabled

Answer (score -1):

GO TO SETTING>GENERAL>Smart keys> then Uncheck the smart indent option.

Comment: Your answer prevents smart indentation altogether, rather than eliminating just the backspace deletion behavior.